# How to select an object as array in PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, object

I have a file from output of Win32_SystemDriver. I need to select an object.
I mapping an object with specific string, then select the object property.
This is the file content that I have (I remove some information).

```
PSComputerName          : MININT-BTE68D2
__GENUS                 : 2
__CLASS                 : Win32_SystemDriver
__SUPERCLASS            : Win32_BaseService
__DYNASTY               : CIM_ManagedSystemElement
__RELPATH               : Win32_SystemDriver.Name="1394ohci"
__PROPERTY_COUNT        : 22
__DERIVATION            : {Win32_BaseService, CIM_Service, CIM_LogicalElement, 
                          CIM_ManagedSystemElement}
__SERVER                : MININT-BTE68D2
__NAMESPACE             : root\cimv2
__PATH                  : \\MININT-BTE68D2\root
DisplayName             : 1394 OHCI Compliant Host Controller
version                 : 10X.0.17763.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

PSComputerName          : MININT-BTE68D2
__GENUS                 : 2
__CLASS                 : Win32_SystemDriver
__SUPERCLASS            : Win32_BaseService
__DYNASTY               : CIM_ManagedSystemElement
__RELPATH               : Win32_SystemDriver.Name="1394ohci"
__PROPERTY_COUNT        : 22
__DERIVATION            : {Win32_BaseService, CIM_Service, CIM_LogicalElement, 
                          CIM_ManagedSystemElement}
__SERVER                : MININT-BTE68D2
__NAMESPACE             : root\cimv2
__PATH                  : \\MININT-BTE68D2\root
DisplayName             : 1313 AHCI Compliant Host Controller
version                 : 10A.5.1111.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

PSComputerName          : MININT-BTE68D2
__GENUS                 : 2
__CLASS                 : Win32_SystemDriver
__SUPERCLASS            : Win32_BaseService
__DYNASTY               : CIM_ManagedSystemElement
__RELPATH               : Win32_SystemDriver.Name="3ware"
__PROPERTY_COUNT        : 22
__DERIVATION            : {Win32_BaseService, CIM_Service, CIM_LogicalElement, 
DisplayName             : 3ware
version                 : 5.01.00.051
```

I mapping the version with string `10X.`, then I need to select an object `DisplayName`. I tried this but It does not return any output.
My expectation, I can get the object of "DisplayName`which is`1394 OHCI Compliant Host Controller`

I tried with this way:

```
$Path = "D:\driver.txt"
$Read = Get-Content $Path | Where-Object {$_ -like "*10X.*"} | Select-Object DisplayName
$Read
```

Anyone can give idea please. Thank you

Comment: When you are reading from file, get-content returns an object of type string (or collection of string as in this case). You need to work with that string, you do not have property Displayname to return! You should work with the output of Win32_SystemDriver directly, or export it into CSV / XML, which would allow you to preserve the object properties!

Comment: Also, where this property Version appear from? Neither Get-WMIObject or Get-CIMInstance return version number in my tests ...

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-wmiobjcet -class win32_pnpentity | where-object {$_.version -like "*10X*"} | select-object DisplayName
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no access to the wmi object. Don't know why and tried the TEXT approach.
This is the way I would do it:

```
Get-Content <infile> | select-string '[^v]10X.*' -AllMatches | %{ $_.Matches } | %{ $_.Value}

10X.0.17763.1 (WinBuild.160101.0800)
```